# AngularJS form validation delayed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I assume the form validation in AngularJS is delayed somehow, which is annoying. I have the following code in my directive's link function:

```
console.log(scope.signinForm.$invalid);   // TRUE
scope.signin.email = 'some@email.com';
scope.signin.password = 'test';
console.log(scope.signinForm.$invalid);   // still TRUE, should be FALSE at this point
```

So I went ahead and used a setTimeout function:

```
var myFunction = function () {
  console.log(scope.signinForm.$invalid); // FALSE, which is correct
};

console.log(scope.signinForm.$invalid);   // TRUE
scope.signin.email = 'some@email.com';
scope.signin.password = 'test';
setTimeout(myFunction, 500);
```

Can someone tell me what I need to do to update $invalid instantly?

Thank you,

Steven

Comment: Just wondering - why do you need to know the validity of the form inside the directive's JS?

Comment: @Ian - because if the form is invalid, I would like to avoid a server roundtrip when she hits the submit button.

Comment: Well, form validity is usually handled in the view, by preventing the submit button from being clicked there - whether you disable or hide it until the form is valid. I don't think the controller/directive should handle that kind of logic. If it matters, here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/m5rg8/

Answer (score 1):

You can try to apply the scope :

```
console.log(scope.signinForm.$invalid);   // TRUE
scope.signin.email = 'some@email.com';
scope.signin.password = 'test';
scope.$apply();
console.log(scope.signinForm.$invalid);
```

Comment: I've tried that.. but then I get the following error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress